# Feedback of "reify"

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, balsamiq, reify

I am new here, so please forgive me if this type of post/question is inappropriate here.

---

Does anyone have used Isomorphic Reify (http://www.smartclient.com/product/reify.jsp)? On "paper" the solution looks promising, but I'd like real field feedback.

Among which:

1. Do you need to use SmartGWT or can you use plain GWT?
2. Do you need the full suite / methodology? (from Isomorphic)
3. How does it behave on updates of forms?

Any help would be very useful.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867451/best-gwt-widget-library

Comment: Yes - I have read it too, but I was specifically looking for info on reify.