# Which widget library is used by Eclipse Che for the client side GWT application?

Tags: user-interface, gwt, eclipse-che

I found out that Eclipse uses GWT to implement its client:

https://che.eclipse.org/hands-on-with-eclipse-che-developing-the-bookmark-plugin-8e171eb1273d

Which of the availabe widget libraries is applied?

Material? Bootstrap? Something else?

A list of GWT widget libraries can be found here:

[Best GWT widget library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867451/best-gwt-widget-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No UI lib is used, just some extensions of GWT widgets and a lot of custom Composites. They also have a custom lightweight MVP and elemental in some widgets.
https://github.com/eclipse/che/tree/master/ide/che-core-ide-ui/src/main/java/org/eclipse/che/ide/ui
https://github.com/eclipse/che/tree/master/ide/che-core-ide-api/src/main/java/org/eclipse/che/ide/api/mvp

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I already saw the ui package but it was not clear to me where the elements in the xml files (e.g. g:FlowPanel) come from. Now I understand that GWT itself provides some widgets and that the inclusion of an additional widget library is optional when using GWT. (Plain GWT-Widgets:  http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefWidgetGallery.html ) If I want to get the same look and feel as Eclipse Che I will have to consider the custom Composites of Eclipse Che and can not just reference an external Javascript UI library.

Comment: The Eclipse Che style sheet Core.css can be found here: https://github.com/eclipse/che/blob/bbd0c1abb23055c285db6f6cf7bf6307744eccf9/ide/che-core-ide-app/src/main/resources/org/eclipse/che/ide/Core.css

and a GWT style sheet for Chrome here:
https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/a90832fec9a56f4cb83ed009c7048e0a8d196fe8/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/theme/chrome/public/gwt/chrome/chrome.css